# Singing: Is it true that all of your power behind singing should come from your diaphragm?

Tags: technique, voice, breathing

I'm not sure if I can ask this here, but I have a question about singing technique. My teacher once told me that all of your power behind singing should come from your diaphragm and that you shouldn't feel pain/tension in your throat. **I interpreted this as "try to feel nothing in your throat".** Is this the correct way to understand this part of singing? This idea was never fully explained to me...

Comment: Sounds like a good interpretation.  Basically, you want the throat to be relaxed.  You might get the best results from not thinking about your throat at all.  Instead, it might be helpful for you to focus your thoughts on your diaphragm.

Answer (score 11):

It is true that most of your singing should come from your diaphragm.  The diaphragm is able to push large volumes of air across your vocal chords with little to no strain on your throat while minimizing any strain on your vocal chords.

**UPDATE:** In reality, (from a purely technical point of view) you don't actually control the diaphragm itself when singing - but it can be controlled by the the internal intercostal muscles and abdominal muscles.  **According to Dr. John Messmer, MD**, Medical Director - Penn State Geisinger Health Group (http://chanteur.net/contribu/index.htm#http://chanteur.net/contribu/cJMdiaph.htm)  ***"To exhale fully, it requires us to contract the abdominal wall muscles and the intercostal muscles (between the ribs) since our diaphragms can not move any higher than fully relaxed."***  But it is easier to just say "use your diaphragm".

You should seek to always avoid singing with your throat. Many singers tighten their throat muscles to sing higher notes. If you do this, you will become hoarse and get a scratchy throat and your vocal cords will become inflamed. If you are tightening your throat too much, your vocal chords will be straining to push sound through a constricted airway in your tightened throat. To some extent tightening of your throat will tighten the muscles surrounding your vocal chords and force them to work harder to vibrate.

Try this exercise. Sing a note that is in the higher end of your range. If you are like many folks, you may feel a tightening of the throat as you sing the higher notes. Next try singing that note while making a conscious effort to push air from your diaphragm and keep your throat relaxed. It takes practice to learn to sing without constricting your throat but if you plan to sing much without straining your "voice" it will be necessary to learn to do this.

Don't forget to always warm up with simple low stress vocal exercises and stay hydrated.

Good luck.

Comment: Pushing up with the diaphragm also helps keep the chest cavity open to maintain chest resonances.

Comment: Your diaphragm is an involuntary muscle - you cannot control it independently of your other muscles. You cannot control your diaphragm any more than your heart. Yes, you can influence your heart to beat faster by moving more, in the same way that you can influence your diaphragm by breathing in and out, but you *cannot* sing "from the diaphragm". It's a visualization exercise that is intended to get singers thinking about their core - their abdominal muscles.  *Those* muscles you can control and *do* influence your breathing / singing.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes yea you're right, I always thought diaphragm = stomach muscles !!

Comment: @RockinCowboy what changes the pitch?? Is that what the throat is for?

Comment: @DarthVoid your throat can alter the pitch but that is not what it is for and should not be used.  Your vocal chords do most of the changing of pitch by changing the length.  You can hum scales without moving your throat or your facial muscles.

Comment: For information on strengthening the muscles that support the diaphragm which as @jjmusicnotes points out is an involuntary muscle, see my answer to this question [http://music.stackexchange.com/a/39076/16897 ]

Comment: @jjmusicnotes  I learned more about the diaphragm muscle in the past two days than I ever had a clue.  It seems that many common assumptions on the part of singers are not exactly physiologically, and anatomically accurate.  But in the overall scheme - the technicalities are not as important as the concept best expressed by the (perhaps scientifically inaccurate) phrase - "sing from your diaphragm".  Thank you for your contribution to my better understanding.

Comment: @ToddWilcox when the diaphragm contracts, it moves down. It is not possible to push up stuff the diaphragm.

Answer (score 6):

The best I can offer is a couple of analogies:  The longest ball I ever hit, in baseball AND in golf, felt like NOTHING on the hands.  Like I had swung at air.  Of course, there was a lot of power going through my hands, as both the baseball (400+ feet) and the golf ball (300+ yards) showed.

Same with the voice.  If you feel it in your throat, then you're dissipating energy there, and that's not helping. The vocal cords are not supposed to be the place where moving air is converted to sound energy...they're supposed to be the place where frequency and tone are shaped.

Comment: So then what changes the pitch? I can do chest voice and I totally feel it coming from my stomach but when I try to go higher is when I strain my throat.

Comment: @DarthVoid - Please don't strain your vocal cords.  They can be damaged so easily.

Comment: 400 feet, 300 yards.  Wow- I'm impressed!  But you make an excellent point.  Proper technique makes power feel almost effortless and using the correct muscles is more effective than using the wrong muscles more forcefully!  Plus one for making that point.

Comment: @RockinCowboy, if I could hit those distances AGAIN, it would be something worthy of mention!!!  But suffice to say, it's a similar concept as singing...where are you "working hard" and where are you allowing the energy to transmit.

Comment: @dwoz  You certainly can't believe everything you read online.  There are apparently many different muscles capable of causing the diaphragm to move.  It does appear that most movements of the diaphragm are caused by involuntary responses (gag reflex, breathing, many others). There seems to be uncertainty even in the scientific community as to whether you can independently control movement of the diaphragm itself or only other muscles that cause it to move.  So  the truth is - we may not know for sure.

Comment: @dwoz  Here is one article that states that the diaphragm is an involuntary muscle (https://innovativeperformanceandpedagogy.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/de-mystifying-support-and-the-diaphragm/)

Answer (score 4):

I must add to previous answers by stating: **The diaphragm is most emphatically *NOT* an involuntary muscle**.

The diaphragm is the sole muscle in the human (and mammalian) body that enables you to breathe. When the diaphragm goes down or up, the lungs fill with air or expel air. There are other muscles that you have in your chest and costal area which you use to aid the diaphragm when you take a deeper than normal breath, but the diaphragm is the lone muscle required for breathing (if you are a mammal).

Every voice teacher/professor in the world will tell you that singing involves learning to bring your diaphragm muscle under voluntary control, and controlling it precisely with every breath you breathe in and breathe out as you sing. (You will also hear that the diaphragm is the single most powerful muscle in the entire human body; it's just that people who do not sing or play a wind instrument are often unaware of their own diaphragm and how to control it. Since this muscle is entirely internal, it isn't visible to you, which is another reason that people might not be aware of it.)

You can certainly control when you breathe and how often you breathe, and you do this by raising and lowering your diaphragm. You can also control whether you take shallow breaths or deep breaths.

Singing is ***breath control***, and ***breath control*** means consciously and voluntarily controlling the movement of your diaphragm.

Everyone, whether they sing or not, knows how to deliberately hold your breath. When you do this you are voluntarily stopping your diaphragm from moving, and it is under your control. However, of course, if you hold your breath too long, your brain will override your willpower and force you to breathe in order to keep yourself from dying. And when you are asleep, your brain will automatically cause your diaphragm to raise and lower so that you continue to breathe when you are unconscious. Involuntary breathing, which everybody does throughout the day, is the reason that some people might wrongly assume that the diaphragm is an involuntary muscle, like those of the heart. But strictly speaking, it is not.

But none of this means that control of the diaphragm is involuntary. Control of the diaphragm is something you can and do for short periods of time when you concentrate on the task. The rest of the time your brain's automatic functions engage and keep you breathing when you are not concentrating on the function.

If the diaphragm were an involuntary muscle, you could not sing with any control.

On the contrary, learning to sing involves learning to control and manipulate and become very aware of your diaphragm and how you control it.

[Wikipedia article on "Diaphragmatic breathing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragmatic_breathing) which is how a human being voluntarily controls the movements of their diaphragm.

[Article from Singingbelt.com on "Breathing and Singing"](http://www.singingbelt.com/how-to-sing/diaphragm-mechanics/)

An excerpt:

> To understand the relationship between singing and breathing, it is
>   first important to see what the diaphragm looks like and learn how it
>   functions. The diaphragm is a large muscle sheath ... that stretches across the bottom of the rib-cage,
>   ... separating the lower organs from the
>   heart and lungs. During normal breathing, the diaphragm naturally
>   flattens drawing air into the lungs, then it releases into a
>   “parachute” shaped position letting the air out of the lungs.
>   “Supporting the voice” and “singing from the diaphragm” means
>   flattening the diaphragm slightly more than during normal breathing
>   and then, maintaining the diaphragm in that position to control the
>   release of air and the air pressure that streams across the vocal
>   cords when you sing. To sing better, a vocalist must learn to preserve
>   that reservoir of air drawn into the lungs when the diaphragm
>   flattens.

Comment: This Wikipedia article also contains a section on the use of breath control in yoga and meditation. I can't make any comment on that. What I'm writing about is the physiology of singing.

Comment: The box at the top of the Wiki article you cite contains this statement: "This article's factual accuracy is disputed."  Singingbelt.com (a marketing site for a product) contains "the intercostal and lateral muscles are held in position, the resulting flattened diaphragm will support the breath".  Plenty of non disputed articles on line state that the diaphragm is an involuntary muscle.  It can be flattened or expanded more vigorously through use of the intercostal and lateral muscles, but the diaphragm itself cannot be consciously contracted accdng 2 plenty of scientifically based articles.

Comment: @RockinCowboy can you cite any of these articles specifically?

Comment: @phoog  I posted that comment over 4 years ago so no - I don't remember which articles I read.  If you have access to Google or Bing, you should be able to find similar articles by searching for "human diaphragm" or something like that.

Comment: @RockinCowboy I looked.  I couldn't find any.  Maybe I need to look harder. 
 Given that breathing is subject to conscious control and also happens without that control during sleep and unconsciousness, I doubt it's actually true that the action of the diaphragm is as involuntary as the heart or the intestines.

Answer (score 2):

Powerful singing comes from a direct connection of the diaphragm to the mask, the front part of your face without involving the larynx which sits open and unmoving in a low relaxed position in the neck as you can verify by lightly touching it.

Anatomically, that description is a load of bull.  But that's what it feels like when you don't constrict your airways unnecessarily and thus cut your resonance chambers into pieces or take from the elasticity of the air column by tensing msucles (like the intercostals) unnecessarily.  This elasticity is both what picks the energy off the vibrating vocal folds and transmits it and what cushions them.  If you impede that flow of sound energy, the vocal folds are wheezing undampened without sound actually arriving at the listeners.

Open pathways and the perception of resonances and activity in mask and diaphragm are core to effective and healthy singing.  "All your power comes from the diaphragm" may not be the best description, it's more like that's where your anchoring point is and you have to keep contact with it.

A singer "fully singing from the diaphragm" will still be hampered by broken ribs and other problems in the air path.

By the way, a good mental aid is wearing a belt and making sure to sing against its resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Singing does NOT come from your diaphragm. Your diaphragm regulates your breath. Singing uses your larynx, epiglottis sphincter and intrinsic and extrinsic laryngeal muscle and cartilage. Do more research on the larynx and you will find your answer.

I  am a vocal specialist with a BA and Masters in this field and have been teaching for 8 years as well as working as a professional vocalist. 
Please ignore everyone that says "sing from your diaphragm". They are ruining young voices in children everywhere by encouraging this "diaphragm way of singing", in turn leading to nodules, polyps,  cysts and various other nasties. 
All the best.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of talk about the involuntary diaphragm, which is almost true. Almost? Yes, because you can sometimes fool them to work. For example, making yourself salivate. It just happens as needed but if you “think” of sucking on a VERY sour lemon, without the need, you will salivate heavier. To use the diaphragm on command, you simply need to think of different verbiage. Again, for example, when singing i’s very high, think A or eh to help soften and not screech. (This is not a diaphragm exercise, but just a difference in sounds). You read the I but THINK A or eh and you will note the change. Babies cry for HOURS with their diaphragm without tiring or getting hoarse. Be a big baby...

Comment: BTW, I was a choirmaster for an Opera Company and helped many to discover that when we sing, we are not talking, we are playing an instrument that NO ONE else can play. With that instrument, we are not singing words, we are making sounds. Understanding that the “sounds” are more important than words is paramount. If the sounds you produce are not melodic, no one is happy. Change the sound. Music publishers publish music but most write the words and separate along the grammatical syllables which is NOT how we sing, “Amazing Grace,” which you read A-maz-ing but you should sing a-may-zing...

Answer (score 1):

I feel the best way to cover this information posted between @RockinCowboy and myself is to add another answer.

All voice teachers teach that singing correctly involves learning to control the movement of your diaphragm muscle. But this is a shorthand way of getting across a more complex concept, involving not only the control of the diaphragm but also other muscles in coordinated, voluntary conjunction. So when we say "sing from your diaphragm" we mean a more elaborate process involving many muscles.

So *practically* speaking, and not strictly physiologically or medically speaking, when you sing you think in terms of controlling your diaphragm, which is true, but it's actually more complicated than that.

I see that @RockinCowboy has just updated his answer with the sentence "But it is easier to just say "use your diaphragm"." I think he and I are finally in agreement here.

Remember that theory follows practice. The technique of singing, and how it is taught, is a combination of the actual experience of singers over the centuries, with references made to anatomy and physiology. Thus a voice teacher would describe all this in different terms than a medical doctor would use. Furthermore there is not 100% agreement among all voice teachers on all points.

I found a [web page on vocal pedagogy](http://www.freezingblue.com/flashcards/print_preview.cgi?cardsetID=110018) which explains things from the point of view of one particular teacher. What I have pasted below is a series of sentences culled from flash cards on that page.

> The muscles and the organs of breathing (trachea,lungs, bronchi,
>   diaphragm, ribs and abdominal and back muscles) act in coordination.
>
> What is the largest muscle in the body? The diaphragm
>
> The diaphragm is the single most important muscle or inhalation or
>   exhalation.
>
> In quiet breathing, inspiration requires only the involuntary
>   contraction, and expiration is an entirely passive process.
>
> What is the main purpose of the intercostal muscles? To aid inhalation
>   and exhalation and help to create a subglottal (below the vocal folds)
>   air pressure for voice use.
>
> By use of intercostal muscles, how is voice use created? Coordinating
>   and balancing the action of the inspiratory and expiratory muscles and
>   by providing checking action to the passive process of respiration.
>
> What is one common misconception of the diaphragm? The first
>   misconception is that diaphragmatic action cannot be consciously
>   controlled , except indirectly as when willing to hold a breath

Answer (score 1):

I think this whole sing with diaphragm concept refers to inhaling not exhaling. But you should aspirate properly in order to sing decently. When you contract your diaphragm during inhalation, you, firstly, take in larger volume of air, secondly you don't expand your rib cage too much.
 Don't forget about the latter though. It's also really important for singing. It's because once expanded, rib cage arbitrary, without use of any muscles, comes back to it's original size and shape. So in order to maintain as big control over your voice as possible, you should minimize the rib cage expansion during aspiration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not, you should just practice powerful singing from your diaghpram as much as possible. Throat, stomach and jaw when you want to really produce power, diaghpram comes natural.